# PayPal REST API using Xamarin

Tags: android, paypal, xamarin, wsdl, xamarin.android

I am implementing PayPal into my Xamarin Android application. 
I am using `OAuth2Authenticator` to get the access token, however, I keep getting the

> Response: Waiting for Activation, Method={null}

I have also tried using the PayPal web services as an alternative (https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl) but I get an exception on the call:

> PayPalService.PayPalAPIAASoapBinding PInterface = new
>   PayPalService.PayPalAPIAASoapBinding ();

I have added myself as a developer on the client's PayPal account. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using PayPal's Windows 8 SDK in your Xamarin project? I successfully imported the library into my Xamarin.Android project and can reference it. You can get the DLL here: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/windows-8-checkout-sdk/gs_win8xo/

Comment: The C# library they created basically handles authentication and server communications for you. It's pretty elegant: http://paypal.github.io/Windows8SDK/csharp.html#buynow

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be trying to use OAuth2 with the older "classic" SOAP API. I don't believe those two are compatible.

Also, you should be careful to never embed any sort of client secret into a binary application that will be distributed widely, as it is quite easy to recover and use for unauthorized access to your account.

Comment: I've read about a different user also got the "500 - Internal Server Error" and that it turned out to be his country not being supported by PayPal. I am situated in South Africa. Would this make a difference?

Comment: Anytime a server returns 500, it's a bug on the backend. But the odds of bugs are much higher if you don't use the API correctly, since the correct behavior would be to simply return a more helpful error. ;)